# How to build a VERY robust PLSQL date parsing function?

Tags: string, oracle, date, parsing, plsql

I have many rows of "date strings", these are strings that a machine learning algorithm has identified as dates. I now need to convert them to **Oracle Dates**, is possible. I would also be interested in getting other date features like "Day of Week", "Day of Month", "Year", "Month".

Here are 10k sample rows of the data I'm dealing with (you'll see a lot of variability in strings):
https://pastebin.com/FUNUynjQ

I was thinking I could try a bunch of different patterns, like this:

```
select  to_date('YYYY-MM-DD') from date_strings
```

But I'm getting this error:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

So I'm thinking I may need to build some massive `CASE` statement or `TRY CATCH` function. Any ideas on best approach here? Thanks!

Comment: Your strings do not have a consistent data type. `2000-2006`, `last may` and `the coming year` are all interval with fixed end-points; `wednesday` is a day-of-the-week that is neither an interval nor a date; `the mid 70s` is a very fuzzy range and in 60 years it will be confusing which 70s you are talking about; `Mar 16, 2021` is a date. You cannot convert them all to Oracle dates as they are not all dates.

Comment: @MT0 you are correct these will not all convert, which is why I added the "if possible" statement. You are also right there is a lot of ambiguity on how to interpret these as dates, I'm just looking for some ideas on how to approach the problem, even if I can only really parse like 20% of them, that's a win.

Comment: I'm starting to think I might just need a bunch of regular expressions to loop through for each value to see if it parses as a date, month, etc.

Comment: Here's the fatal flaw with _anything_ you come up with:  Consider the "date" string '05/04/12'.  What is the month?  What is the day?  What is the year?  How do you know? It would certainly be possible to write an algorithm that will convert it to oracle DATE without error, but you will have no way of knowing if it was _correct_.

Comment: @EdStevens you are correct, you don't know if it was supposed to be a MM/DD or DD/MM, but that's OK. Parsing these strings to dates (even if they are a little wrong) is way better than not parsing them at all, so I still need a way to do this, even though the source data is messy.

Comment: If your machine learning algorithm has identified them as dates why is it then not able to return them as DATE values?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it's a 3rd party library that is able to recognize things that "look like dates", based on what it's been trained on. So it just provides strings like I referenced in the paste bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy enough to iterate over potential format masks assuming that you can define a priority order for them (i.e. declare that 05/04/12 is more likely to be May 4, 2012 than April 5, 2012 or May 4, 1912 or April 12, 2005).  This also makes some default assumptions (the string "2005" becomes April 1, 2005 if you run it on April 1, 2021) which may or may not be reasonable.  I'm also using the newer "default on conversion error" syntax to avoid a bunch of exception handling.  If you're stuck on an old version you can put a `begin exception end` inside the loop.

```
create or replace function guess_date( p_date_str )
  return date
is
  type format_model_tbl is table of varchar2(100);
  l_formats format_model_tbl := format_model_tbl( 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                                                  'dd/mm/yyyy',
                                                  'dd Mon, yyyy',
                                                  'yyyy-mm-dd',
                                                  'Day',
                                                  'YYYY' );
  l_date date;
begin
  for d in (<<your select statement>>)
  loop
    for fmt in 1 .. l_formats.count
    loop
      l_date := to_date( p_date_str default NULL on conversion error, 
                         l_formats(fmt) );
      if( l_date is not null )
      then 
        return l_date;
      end if;
    end loop;
  end loop;

  return null;
end;
```

You could extend this.  Rather than a collection of format models, you could have a collection of format models and non-default conversion functions that you call.  So, for example, if you wanted "2005" to resolve to the date "Jan 1, 2005", you could write a "convert_bare_year" function, associate that with the 'YYYY' format model, and call that when the basic conversion succeeded.  Something like this where in the loop you invoke dynamic SQL if a non-default conversion function is specified.

```
create type conversion_typ is object (
  format_model varchar2(100),
  conversion_func varchar2(100)
);

create type conversion_tbl is table of conversion_typ; 

create or replace function guess_date( p_date_str )
  return date
is
  l_coversions conversion_tbl := conversion_tbl( 
                                    conversion_typ( 'mm/dd/yyyy', null ),
                                    conversion_typ( 'dd/mm/yyyy', null ),
                                    ...
                                    conversion_typ( 'yyyy', 'custom_convert_bare_year' )
                                  );
  ...
```

Comment: Brilliant. The "default NULL on conversion error" was something I didn't know about, but that's really useful.

Comment: _"i.e. declare that 05/04/12 is more likely to be May 4 than April 5). "_   And even that is assuming the '12' is year.  And whatever is the year, assuming the century.  Don't forget Y2k!